# java - do objects created in methods only live for the life of the method execution?

Tags: java, oop

I'm programming a java app and trying to educate myself on memory management. If instantiate a String object in a method of an object that's already been created, will that String object exist in memory after the method is executed? Take this example. Does newString exist in memory after i execute myObject.setNewName()? or does java destroy those objects if they are not instance variables?

```
public class MyObject(){

    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public myObject(Integer id, String name){
        this.id   = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNewName(){

        String newString = "This is a new name";
        this.name = newString;
    }
}
```

another file

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(4,"Bob");

myObject.setNewName();
```

Comment: What difference does it make? Can you write some Java code that can tell the difference? The implementation does whatever it needs to in order to make the code work.

Comment: it helps me understand a bit about memory management and oop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the reference to the object is held beyond the method, for example assigned to a field, then the object won't be garbage collected when the method ends.

Objects only assigned to local variables will be "not reachable" when the method ends, so will be marked for garbage collection.

It's all to do with scope. If the reference to the object is still in scope, it will remain in memory.

Comment: ok awesome. Thanks. This makes sense. The whole idea of garbage collection is new to me. This clears things ups

Comment: This answer is the best in general.

Answer (score 1):

String is actually created in a constant pool,and will be exists through the whole JVM lifecycle.You can check it as follow:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    aMethod();
    String str1 = "This is a string";
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str1)); 
}

public static void aMethod(){
    String str0 = "This is a string";
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(str0));
}
```

str0 and str1 is actually the same because their hashcode equals.

Strings are kind of specific objects,If a common object's is no longer referenced by anyone ,It will be GC-ed at sometime and the memory will be recircled.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the string literals (e.g. `"This is a new name"`) are interned, they will be cached and remain in memory even after the method ends.

But, generally objects are gc'ed once the variable(s) referencing the object go(es) out of scope.

e.g `String newString = new String("This is a new name");`, then the object would be eligible for gc once the method returns because `newString` would be longer there holding the reference to the object.

Note: That doesn't mean you should use `new String("This is a new name")` instead of `"This is a new name", because interning happens in both the cases. The difference is that with`new String("This is a new name")` you are creating one extra object explicitly.

Comment: is there a practical benefit for doing new String("This is a new name")?

Comment: @David: You can read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an object it's volatility (and thus the objects contents) will have the lifespan of the method/object that has declared it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you hold a reference to it, the object still will remain in memory. Once the string is not referenced by any object, it will become garbage-collectable, which means the memory will be recovered at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, the scenario you are asking about overlaps two aspects of Java memory management, meaning your answer is both yes and no.

```
String newString = "This is a new name";
```

This line will be held in memory from the first allocation through to the end of the program, as it is referencing a string literal, which is static. The compiler does this because it can guarantee `"This is a new name"` will never change, so it's useless CPU cycles to allocate, reallocate and delete it every time the method is run.

On the other hand, if the line was, for example

```
String newString = new Object().toString();
```

This is not a literal, and so a new object (which is a `String`) is create during each new run of the method. So, when is this object deallocated? You can guarantee it will survive to the end of the method, as it is referenced by `newString`. After that, it will survive until the next time the garbage collector runs. However, nothing will have a reference to it any more, so it's impossible to access anyway.

Comment: interesting...and confusing at the same time. So is it bad practice to use string literals in methods?

Comment: Not at all. In fact, it's better from a performance standpoint. The only issue some people have is with readability, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it.